# Displaying Multiple Boxes On Right Side of Screen

Tags: html, css

I am currently working on a Website for someone and on their about page, they want to have some testimonials on there.  They want each little sentence displayed inside it's own box on the right side of the screen.  I have put the text they requested at the top of the page, and have inserted on block with a quote in it.  This is where I am running into a problem.  No matter what I do, whether it be with float or display, I can not get the boxes to run vertically along the side of the page, each one displaying below the previous one.  Could someone please help me to make this work.  I have tried to float the blocks to no avail.  They just want to pile next to each other.  Here is the code:

HTML

```
<aside id="expert">
     <h2>Always a Satisfied Customer</h2>

    <ul class="b">
        <li>Upfront Pricing</li>
        <li>Affordable Rates</li>
        <li>Courteous and Respectful</li>
        <li>Always On Time</li>
    </ul>
</aside>

<aside id="refer">
    <p>I would recommend EJP to anyone and everyone! They showed up, looked at my issue, and fixed it promptly. They are simply the best!
        <br />-Tim S.</p>
</aside>
```

CSS

```
#expert {
    background-color: white;
    display: block;
    border: solid;
    float: right;
    right: 20px;
}
#refer {
    background-color: white;
    border: solid;
    float: right;
    width: 150px;
    display: block;
}
```

Thank you

Comment: Could you give us the code you've mad so far? It's hard to say what you're doing wrong without actually seeing your code. Best is if you could put the code in a JSFiddle that reproduces the problem. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry,  forgot to add the code.  Here it is:                                          #expert {background-color: white;
   display: block;
   border: solid;
   float: right;
   right: 20px;}



#refer {background-color: white;
  border: solid;
  float: right;
  width: 150px;
  display: block;
  }

Comment: You can edit your question and add the code there. You should also add your HTML so that everyone can get a clear idea of what you've created.

Comment: Just did that,  I wasn't thinking when I fixed it

Comment: @kylenarovich It would be usefull to aslo include some HTML, so we can make a solution that fits your situation instead of just assuming what your HTML would look like.

Answer (score 0):

You can make them stack like so:

```
#refer {
    ...
    float: right;
    clear: right;
}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/gphoL379/)**

Comment: Wow, thanks for the help.  Had I looked a little harder, I would have probably gotten it.  Thank you very much.  You just saved the day!!  How would I put a little space between the boxes, instead of having them touching?  Thanks again

Comment: Also, use a common class on all testimonials. Don't target IDs for CSS when possible.

Comment: Never mind, I don't know why I asked that question.  I know how to fix it.  Thank you to all!